# Как сделать слайдер фото с увеличением?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Как сделать слайдер фото с увеличением?**

Желательно, без *JS*, но если нужно, то готов разобраться.

Нужно, чтобы была навигация между картинками.

**Спасибо!**

```css
.product.art.001 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#Nashi_Tseny_product.art.001 {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 106.9vh;
}
#container2_product.art.001 {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 109.9vh;
}
.pre-title_product-page{
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold;
    font-size: 2vh;
}
.product-page-title {
    font-size: 3vh
}
.pre-title_product-page a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.first-pre-title_product-page {
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.second-pre-title_product-page {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.items-section_product-page {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background: url(/img/fon_2.png);
}
.items_product-page {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    margin-top: -1vh;
}
.item_1_product-page {
    border: 0.2vh dashed rgba(000, 000, 000, .7);
    border-radius: 0.8vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .25);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 44.5vh;
    padding-top: 2.65vh;
    box-shadow: 0vh 0vh 1.5vh 0vh rgb(333,333,333);
}
.item_2_product-page {
    border: 0.2vh dashed rgba(000, 000, 000, .7);
    border-radius: 0.8vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .25);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 35vh;
    margin-left: 2.5vh;
    padding-top: 2.65vh;
    box-shadow: 0vh 0vh 015vh 0vh rgb(333,333,333);
}
.photo-item_product-page img {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 38vh;
    border-radius: 0.5vh;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 0.15vh dashed white;
}
.text-item-description_product-page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 86.8%;
    height: 53%;
    background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, .35);
}
.title-item_product-page {
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-top: 0.1vh;
}
.cost-item_product-page {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 14.5vh;   
}
.product-description {
    display: block;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, .5);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    border: 0.2vh solid black;
}
.product-description-title {
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2vh;
    padding-left: 5vh;
    padding-top: 1.1vh;
}
.product-description-text {
    width: 91.5vh;
    height: 30vh;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-left: 3.9vh;
    border: 0.1vh dotted black;
    border-radius: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<main class="product.art.001">
     
     <section class="items-section_product-page">
      <div id="container2_product.art.001">
       <div id="Nashi_Tseny_product.art.001">
        <h2 class="product-page-title">Архиерейское облачение:</h2>
        <div class="pre-title_product-page">
         <div class="first-pre-title_product-page">
       </div>
        </div>
       <div class="items_product-page">
        <div class="item_1_product-page">
         <div class="photo-item_product-page">
          <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841236/v841236334/39899/gzL2raZD1S0.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="product-description">
        <div class="product-description-title">Описание:</div>
        <div class="product-description-text">
         
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: Ну зачем Вам это. Используйте библиотеки, давно все написано за вас. [ссылка на слайдер](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, подскажите, а как с данного сайта нудный слайдер?Могу задать в отдельный вопрос и дать ссылку, если хотите

Comment: на сайте есть ссылка `usage`, все по пунктам делаете и все работает)